# Hide and unhide rows in Excel VBA when specific value in the one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide/unhide if a specific value is selected from a drop down list. As long as it works, it could be under the worksheet code (when the value is selected) or when a button is pushed. Your help is greatly appreciated.
I have tried with this code unsuccessfully..

```
Application.EnableEvents = False

If DWR.Cells(4, 14) = "CANTI" Then
    DWR.Activate
    DWR.Range("10:49").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    'must hide the empty rows
    DWR.Activate
    DWR.Range("50:89").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf DWR.Cells(4, 14) = "F100" Then
    DWR.Activate
    DWR.Range("50:89").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    'must hide the empty rows
    DWR.Activate
    DWR.Range("10:49").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What type of drop down list do you have? A control (e.g. Form control, ActiveX control) or a spreadsheet validation list that acts as the drop down?

Comment: What does "unsuccessfully" mean in this case? More detail would be helpful.

Comment: I have data validation list with three possible choices CANTI, F100 and ALL.

Comment: It will not happen automatically unless you put the code in the worksheet change event.

Comment: Unsuccessfully means that when all rows are unhidden, hides them only ones and then does not follow the logic. Meaning that, if Canti is chosen, and all rows were not hidden it will hide the F100 part, but afterwards it's stays just like that no matter what is chosen on click of the button.

Comment: In fact both your scenarios are the same.

Comment: @SJR Could you be more specific? Should I put it in the sheet like that. What do you mean by change event? Thanks.

Comment: In both cases you are hiding rows 50-89 so you need to reverse the logic in one case.

Comment: Oh, gosh... True that. What a silly one! Thanks @SJR

Comment: Re my other point see, e.g. https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Then

        Application.EnableEvents = False

            Range("10:89").EntireRow.Hidden = False     '~~~> Default case: display ALL rows

            If Target = "CANTI" Then
                Range("10:49").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Range("50:89").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ElseIf Target = "F100" Then
                Range("10:49").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Range("50:89").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If

        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End If
End Sub
```